# Text shadow on iPad, strange behavior leaving shadow stain where not wanted

Tags: ios, css, ipad, shadow

I have a following problem. It seems to happen only on the iPad. I use a text shadow on a paragraph but as you can see circled on [this screenshot](http://www.digital-ant.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/shadow-problem.jpg), it leaves weird "stains" where it shouldn't be.

the page where it is happening: http://www.digital-ant.com/clients/

CSS:

```
.shadow {
    overflow: visible;
    text-shadow: 0 0 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Any idea why is that happening? And why only on iPad?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using webkit shadows? IOS uses a different way to render those effects so I always add a webkit style definition too.
This article shows the use of the fallback style definitions: http://blog.michelledinan.com/01/2012/css3-text-shadow/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your idea. I have added webkit shadows, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue on my iPad Air 2 running the latest iOS version in safari. which version do you use?

Comment: It's happening on iPad Mini 2, and the iOS version is the latest 9